# backbone sync callback always use error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the callback to work correctly when using Backbone sync. I am looking at my return packets and the response code is 200 which is no error, yet the alert("fail") statement gets called. I am requesting a response from a java servlet. Any idea guys? Thanks

```
Backbone.sync("read", this.model, {
  url : "some url",
    success: function(model, response) {
      alert(response);
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
      alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Hien WTH are you doing!! From the docs it clearly states you override sync method on the `model`or `backbone` global instance. Function recieves **method, model, options** where `options = {success:fn,error:fn}` may be now you will understand what's wrong

Comment: @Deeptechtons Um... from what I have read, all it said is that I may override it if I want different behavior. I thought the default behavior was that it passed my model as a JSON to the url.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are doing...

Use this methods instead of sync:

```
model.fetch();
model.save();
model.destroy();
```

They will call sync, and they work perfectly.

I don't think it's necessary to override the original sync, it is good enough. I created a mock sync for an example application, this is how it works:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    notAllowedEmailHost: "gmail.com",
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        if (method == "read" || method == "delete")
            throw new Error("Example is not prepared for these methods.");
        var email = model.get("email");
        var status = 201;
        if (email.indexOf(this.notAllowedEmailHost) != -1)
            status = 400;
        else if (method == "update")
            status = 500;
        options.xhr = {
            status: status
        };
        if (status >= 400)
            options.error(options.xhr);
        else
            options.success({
                id: 1
            });
    }
});
```

The methods above create wrapper functions around your callbacks, and in sync those wrappers are called with the result. So the callback in sync is not the callback you give by the call of fetch, save or destroy functions...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your servlet returns a JSON object, even if it's empty. This fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: I tried to "update" collection, by using Backbone.sync('update', myCollection,{success:function(){alert('sucess');}});  and no 'sucess' was called(even though 200_OK received from server). ONLY AFTER making sure my server return a json(even an empty one) as @Vlad suggested, the 'success' alert popup